# How to mix in UIButton in UILabel text?

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift2, uilabel

I'm trying to have notification table cells that will have labels along the lines of "User1 became friends with User2", where User1 & User2 are buttons that open a profile view of said user. The problem occurs when the text wraps around. Example:

```
                WANT                              DON'T WANT
|                                      |  |                           |
| "John Doe" became friends with "Jane |  | "John" friends with "Jane"|
| Smith"                               |  |                     "Doe "|
 ^notice how to wraps around               wraps within btn bounds^
  all the way back to left margin
```

I pretty much want the Swift equivalent of this HTML: `<a href=..>Button 1</a> some plain text <a href=..>Button 2</a>`. Is there a way I could accomplish this?

Comment: I would recommend achieving this functionality using 'Attributed Text', and adding a tap gesture recognizer to the attributed text that opens the profile of the tapped user.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using UITextView. UITextView Detects urls and you can use that feature like this.

You can add dummy url values for those clickable values and then values become clickable in uitextview. Here is the sample code :-

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

  let user01 = "http://www.dummyLinks";
  let user02 = "http://www.dummy.com/privacy";

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.textView.delegate = self
      let labelText = "Chathuranga Silva is now Freind with Jason"
      let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelText)
      var textRange = string.mutableString.rangeOfString("Chathuranga Silva")
      string.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: user01, range: textRange)
      textRange = string.mutableString.rangeOfString("Jason")
      string.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: user02, range: textRange)
      textView.attributedText = string
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
      if (URL.absoluteString == user01) {
          print("Selected user01")
      } else if (URL.absoluteString == user02) {
          print("Selected user02")
      }
      return false
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, I was a bit to general in my explanation however, instead of an actual website link, I would want the button to go to a different view controller. Like `*user1* went to *the park*` where `user1` opens up a profile view controller and `the park` opens up a different view controller. Is there any way to use the addAttribute to achieve this?

Comment: Just use segues where I used print

Comment: Btw you not need to give actual web link its a dummy one just give a url to make label word is clickable